# mysql - enable MEMORY(HEAP) storage engine

Tags: mysql

How do I enable the [MEMORY(HEAP)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) storage engine in MySQL?  This might be more suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is automatically enabled.